# How do I fly a minicopter?

Tags: rust

I found a minicopter along a road, and decided to test it out. I tossed some fuel in it and attempted to start it up. I managed to get it a few feet off the ground before I went careening off into a tree and exploded. How does one fly a minicopter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A little hard to explain, but:**

"**W**" and "**S**" are for the power of your rotor. (Just like to accelerate and to break)

With "**A**" and "**D**" you can turn the whole heli on his X -Axis. (Horizontal)

The difficult part of flying is controlling the heli with your mouse! 
When moving the mouse **up**, your heli will **face down**.(In combination with a highly rotor power, by pressing w before and during moving you mouse, you'll go fast forward).

When moving the mouse **down** you will **break** your forward flying, but you can also easily **crash** your heli with this, by pulling to far or to fast.

Moving the mouse to the left and to the right will **lean** your heli to the site, which also often leads to crashes!
Start your heli training by pressing "**W**" and then moving your mouse just a tiny bit up. Control you helis direction with "**A**" and "**D**" mostly.

To drive the heli around on the ground, just keep pressing **CTRL** while moving with "**WASD**".

Just keep in mind to use your mouse very **carefully** while flying! 
There are also some Modded Community Servers, just for heli training. :)

Comment: Found a server to test it on. thanks for the break down of the controls, i can kind of fly it now, but nothing crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch this video to gain an understanding of how to operate the Minicopter

The short version is:
Use the <kbd>W</kbd> & <kbd>S</kbd> keys to control the engine’s speed
Use the <kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>D</kbd> keys to control the yaw (left and right directions)
Use the <kbd>mouse</kbd> to control the pitch (elevation)